# How to fix npm package after upgrading npm and nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

In this case i how to fix [protractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor) .

i have installed protractor `v1.6.1` globally use npm v below 2 and node below 1.

Along the way i update both `npm` and `node`, now i use `npm v3.7.2` and `node v4.2.6`. As the protractor say about it's [compatibility](https://github.com/angular/protractor) say i should use version 3, which match `node v 4`.

i stupidly do delete manually the old protractor `v1.6.1`
when i install new protractor which is `v3.1.1` it say located on

```
X:\nodejs
`-- protractor@3.1.1
```

but when i have to verify it's working, with `protractor --version`. It yell like so :

```
Error cannot find module `X:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
at ...
```

how to fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of [protractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor) moving or delete these file just solve the problem if you configure `npm`, `nodejs` properly and install new `protractor` successfully.

```
X:\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor
X:\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor.md
```

for save i also move

```
X:\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager
X:\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager.md
```

You can also choose to use npm which installed on the `nodejs installation dir`.
For detail about doing that you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows) (option 3).

For choosing the option you can prefer with the `npm config prefix` which currenly you use. To know about it run the following command :

```
npm config get prefix -g
```

i choose option 3 because currently my machine use

```
X:\nodejs
```

as it's prefix. For windows and troubleshooting related you can read [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#a-brief-note-on-the-built-in-windows-configuration), and for npm config prefix itself you can read [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix)